# How can I write this SQL-Statement correctly

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to make an uptate to a table with thee following Statement:

```
UPDATE plz_buland_kreis SET KFZKZ='A' 
WHERE Kreis IN ( SELECT kreis FROM plz_buland_kreis WHERE Kreis LIKE 'Augsburg%' )
```

I get the following error:

> MySQL meldet:   1093 - Table 'plz_buland_kreis' is specified twice,
>   both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

Is it possible to write this SQL-Statement correctly?

Answer (score 3):

You can try below -

```
Update plz_buland_kreis set KFZKZ='A' where Kreis like 'Augsburg%'
```